# Minimising the distance from the origin to a level surface

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the function $h(x, y, z) = x^2 − 2y^2 + 3z^2$,
and its level surface S through the point $(1, 1, 1)$. Determine the shortest distance
from S to the origin by considering the function $f(x, y, z) = x^
2 + y^
2 + z^
2$
and
writing down the Lagrangian for finding the minimum of $f$ subject to $(x, y, z)$
lying on S. Determine the critical points and by comparison of the values of $f$ at these points determine the minimum distance.

So I've set up the Lagrangian, $L = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - \lambda(x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 -2)$

and found the partial derivatives with respect to each variable:

$L_x = 2x - 2\lambda x = 0$

$L_y = 2y + 4\lambda y = 0$

$L_z = 2z - 6\lambda z = 0$

$L_{\lambda} = x^2 -2y^2 +3z^2 - 2 = 0$

Firstly, am I correct in saying the level Surface S is given by subbing in the point (1,1,1), and secondly where do I go from here to find the minimum distance? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am having trouble solving these simultaneous equations. Could you give me a hint of how to begin when you have a set like this? I always get tangled up easily.

Comment: From the first we have =1 or x=0. So if we choose =1 we have y=0,z=0 and then x=+-sqrt(2) from the last equation for example. Now choose x=0 and do similar steps. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x-2xa%3D0+%2C2y%2B4ay%3D0+%2C2z%E2%88%926az%3D0+%2Cx%5E2%E2%88%922y%5E2%2B3z%5E2%E2%88%922%3D0

Comment: Why do we ignore the value of $\lambda = -1/2$ as a solution of $L_y$ ? Wolfram alpha doesn't list that as a solution.

Comment: @Extended The second derivative test that you reference doesn’t work for constrained optimization problems. The points that the Lagrange multiplier method produces can’t be critical points of the unconstrained function: for the Lagrange multiplier method to apply at a point, the gradients of the objective function and constraints must all be nonzero.

Comment: @amd By any chance, could you help explain an answer to my comment above? I still don't really understand why we disregard this value?

Comment: It doesn’t lead to a solution of the entire system. Try it. You’ll eventually end up with something like $-2y^2-2=0$, which has no real solutions.